# Shell script to backup VMware VM's, exporting each VM to a list then asking user intput

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, user-input

What I'm Trying To Accomplish:

- Get list of Virtual Machines ".vmx" file and place in variables
- Give the user and choice of which VM to backup
- Use "ovftool" to produce an export of the chosen VM to a hardcoded location

What I Have So Far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# MyVariables
#vmFolder=
#vmList=
#vmDestination="~/Desktop/"
vmTool="/Applications/VMware OVF Tool/ovftool"

# DatScript
for i in "/Users/$USER/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/"* ; do
   if [ -d "$i" ]; then
     echo $(basename "$i")
   fi
done
```

Still getting used to Bash and FWIW I'm writing this for OS X 10.8 but thought the Unix SE would be best.

Comment: @Anthon it says you edited my post but I don't see anything different? And is this post in the correct spot?

Comment: You can click on the link 'edited X hours ago' above the last editors (my) image to the left of yours. You will see the edit history. There should be people here who can help you out with bash scripts, although I would do such a thing in a Python program. So yes it should be ok here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script I just wrote https://github.com/Yafet-Getachew/vmbackuputil.git. It loops through multiple virtual machines in Virtualbox (I'm sure you can do some modifications for vmware) and backs them up to a remote server. You can delete the bottom half of the script and just get the OVA files.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#   Backup Virtual Machines to SERVERNAME 
#
#
#

# create array with names, ips, usernames and passwords of virtual machines
echo
echo "Backup utility for VirtualBox virtual machines"
echo

ssh-add

declare -A virtualmachines

virtualmachines=(
    [VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME]="VIRTUAL_MACHINE_IPADDRESS"
    )

users=(
    [VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME]="VIRTUAL_MACHINE_USERNAME"
    )

passwords=(
    [VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME]="VIRTUAL_MACHINE_USER_PASSWORD"
    )

#make a directory 
mkdir -p backup-vms

#check if sshpass is installed and install it if not
if ! (dpkg-query -l sshpass) > /dev/null; then
   echo -e "sshpass not installed, installing (sudo might be required)... "
   sudo apt install sshpass
fi



# loop through virtual machines and shut them down
for i in "${!virtualmachines[@]}"
do

    echo "shutting down $i through ip ${virtualmachines[$i]}"
    sshpass -p ${passwords[$i]} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${users[$i]}@${virtualmachines[$i]} sudo poweroff

    echo "Waiting for machine $i to poweroff..."

    until $(VBoxManage showvminfo --machinereadable $i | grep -q ^VMState=.poweroff.)

    do
      sleep 1
      echo "poweroff state not reached for $i"
    done

    echo "poweroff of $i successful, building ova"
    echo

    # build .ova in home directory to then transport to medemer
    VBoxManage export $i -o backup-vms/$i-$(date +"%m-%d-%y").ova

    # Copy backed up file to remote backup folder
    rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -avzpi --progress backup-vms BACKUP_SERVER_USER@BACKUP_SERVER_IP:~/backup/backup-vms
    #rm -rf backup-vms/*

    echo "SUCCESSFUL BACKUP OPERATION"
done

echo
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your contribution, but answer on this site should not require clarification from the asker. Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Thanks @Morpheus.47. I'll take a look at this and test it out. I didn't get a notification saying this was answered so my apologies for the time it's taken to respond.